# docker-compose is not working on Docker Beta for OS X

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker Version 1.11.1-beta11 (build: 6974) on OS X (which is native). It has a fancy migration tool to help you to move images from docker-machine to native docker (or something like that). Everything was working perfect, I even was able to start containers through docker-compose but then I rebooted my laptop and now docker-compose is not recognizing new docker engine I guess because I'm getting:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

So I believe docker-compose still thinks I'm using or depending on docker-machine to start containers.

Any idea about how to workaround this issue?

**Update:**

Docker env variables:

```
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/myuser/.docker/machine/machines/default
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
```

Comment: Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: @KevanAhlquist yes. UI says so, I also see docker processes through activity monitor. I started the container through kitematic (for now) but it'd be nice to not depend on that interface, I don't see it supports docker-compose

Comment: What do your docker environment variables look like?

Comment: @KevanAhlquist I just updated the question with that info

Comment: I'm guessing that those are my problem since I won't be using docker-machine anymore. Am I right?

Comment: My guess is before the reboot compose was still talking to the docker-machine vm, after the reboot that machine isn't running anymore. Does the native client expose its socket location and certs?

Comment: About your guest. I did shut down docker-machine to make sure native client was proving the engine. But not sure about your question about socket and certs. UI client doesn't seem to provide an interface for that yet

Comment: Ok. Found something interesting. Docker works but docker-compose do not. Which makes things easier, I'm checking updates for docker-compose right now

Comment: Fixed. I just commented out the docker env variables set by docker-machine and update docker-compose. Everything is perfect!. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the docker env variables from my rc script (~/.zshrc) and upgraded docker-compose version to 1.7.1. Also made sure sure docker-machine was down